vmware-vdiskmanager.exe Failed to load OpenSSL config file
I'm trying to repair a vmware vdisk that won't start after a power outage. The instructions say to run vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -R <path-to-vdisk> but it didn't work for me:
SSLConfigLoad: Failed to load OpenSSL config file.

This on Win 10 with Workstation 17.5.2. I tried it both from elevated (Administrator) an unelevated prompts, but it makes no difference.
Apparently it works for some, as recently as a year ago, but others (in comments there) reported the same error I see.
The 369-page manual has about zero "repair" words, by the way.

I've also tried a fresh install of Win 11 (that I have on another drive with no ASUS etc. bloatware or any possible OpenSSL conflict--unless Windows itself creates one somehow, lately) plus a fresh install of WS 17.5.2 in that OS instance [it had no virtualization SW before] and I can say for sure that in 17.5.2 vmware-vdiskmanager is broken 'out of the box'. One would probably have to use a different version of WS for that repair tool work.
So, how do I fix it? (Or rather what's the last version of WS in which vmware-vdiskmanager worked?)

I suspect this is related to the fact that they've apparently removed (at some point) the built-in VM server that use to ship with WS15.5[.7]. Or at least the option to configure its port has disappeared in WS 17. And vdiskmanager is perhaps trying to connect to that. (I stayed away from the 16.x branch due to its more numerous bugs.) I see the built-in server was an issue in other ways so perhaps that's why they've axed it.

I suspect this is due to conflicting openSSL installations. I see both vagrant and the ASUS bloatware installed some on this box https://i.postimg.cc/D064k027/image.png

I've uninstalled vagrant now, but the error persists. So, if it's a conflict, it's with the ASUS Armory Crate.

Alas it isn't a simple conflict with some other OpenSSL! It turns out in 17.5.2 this tool is 'broken out of the box'.

I fixed it for me. It's a slightly complicated story, but hopefully others will be able to learn from it, so here it goes (skip to the end for TLDR):

The Failed to load OpenSSL config file is a red herring. The real issue is that -R for repair silently fails/succeds. (Found that on some Russian forum... as Broadcom's are a mess now.) To make this tool say something meaningful about the real reason for failure, you have to try -D for instance, for defragment.

In my case for the latter it complained that:
This disk is read-only in the snapshot chain in 'e:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\packer-20240609-231917.vmx'.
In this chain you may only modify the following disk(s):
   - e:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000010.vmdk

So far so good, but... trying to fix the latter,
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -R e:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000010.vmdk
SSLConfigLoad: Failed to load OpenSSL config file.

But didn't actually fix it (failed silently again, as to the real reason). WS still failed to load that VM!
OTOH, knowing we have to try something other than -R for meaningful error messages... I tried -d:
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation>vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -d e:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000010.vmdk
SSLConfigLoad: Failed to load OpenSSL config file.
Failed to open the disk 'e:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000010.vmdk' : The parent of this virtual disk could not be opened (0x3e8c).
Failed to defragment: The parent of this virtual disk could not be opened (0x3e8c).

Now it tell us  the real reason why it was failing, it could not find the parent. Whyy not??
A deep dive into the vmdk format found that this is was monolithic disk with an embedded descriptor. So what's in the descriptor in this case?

As you can see, the paths are relative. But apparently vmware-vdiskmanager.exe cannot follow them unless you cd into the VM storage folder first.
When I did the latter, we got a little closer to the solution. Now -e tells us where the problem lies.
E:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop>"c:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe" -e disk-cl2-000010.vmdk
SSLConfigLoad: Failed to load OpenSSL config file.
Failed to open the disk 'E:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000010.vmdk' : The parent of this virtual disk could not be opened (0x3e8c).
Disk link E:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000010.vmdk successfully opened.
Failed to open the disk 'E:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop\disk-cl2-000009.vmdk' : The specified virtual disk needs repair (0x3e86).
Disk chain is not consistent: The parent of this virtual disk could not be opened (0x3e8c).

The odd thing about this case is that it wasn't disk 10--the last one-- that was corrupt, but disk 9 before it. And -R will not automatically fix that if you point it to the last one in the chain. You have to tell it precisely which one to fix, back in history.
E:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop>"c:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe" -R disk-cl2-000010.vmdk
SSLConfigLoad: Failed to load OpenSSL config file.

Still fails/succeeds silently, even from the VM dir. But
E:\vm\agra\boxes\g-VAGRANTSLASH-ubu22\0\vmware_desktop>"c:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe" -R disk-cl2-000009.vmdk
SSLConfigLoad: Failed to load OpenSSL config file.
The virtual disk, 'disk-cl2-000009.vmdk', was corrupted and has been successfully repaired.

After that I was able to start the VM in WS and it repaired its own file system from there (btrfs in my case).

So, moral of this story (or TLDR)

OpenSSL complaints from vmware-vdiskmanager are a red herring and can be safely ignored.
Do cd into the VM dir before doing any vmware-vdiskmanager if your vdisks chains use relative paths.
First check with -e which disk in the chain is actually corrupt. Because -R is 'dumb' and won't do that for you.
Finally, fix the right disk in the chain with -R.

